# How can I improve this loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Once again, i'm still getting the hang of python. I made a program that has the user guess a 'magic number', randomly generated by the computer. After 5 incorrect tries, it provides a hint in the form of an addition problem using two randomly generated variables whose sum is equal to the magic number.

This is the code:

```
def moot():
    count = 0
    # magicNumber is the randomly generated number from 1 to 100 that must be guessed
    magicNumber = random.randint(1,100) 
    var1 = 0 
    var2 = 0
    guess = eval(input('Enter a number: '))
    # This loop sets random values for var1 and var2 that sum up to the magicNumber

    while var1 + var2 != var: 
        var2 = random.randint(1,100)
        var3 = random.randint(1,100)
    # an addition problem is made from var1 and var2 to be used as a hint later
    hint = 'Try adding '+ str(var1)+ ' and '+ str(var2)+'\n'
    # withinRange checks to see if the users guess is (valid) within the range of 1 to 100
    # if not, asks for another number until a valid one is provided
    withinRange = True if (guess <= 100 and guess >= 1) else False  

    while not withinRange:
        count = count + 1
        guess = eval(input('Number is invalid.Enter a number between 1 and 100: '))
        withinRange = True if (guess <= 100 and guess >= 1) else False
    # rng tells the user if his guess is too high or low
    rng = 'low' if guess < magicNumber else 'high'

    # the following loop repeatedly asks for input until the user enteres the majicNumber
    while magicNumber != guess:
        count = count + 1
        print('\nThats incorrect. Your number is too',rng,end='\n')
        # after 5 incorrect guesses the program prints out the addition problem that
        # was made using var1 and var2
        if count > 5:
            print(hint)
        guess = eval(input('Guess: '))
        withinRange = True if (guess <= 100 and guess >= 1) else False
        while not withinRange:
            count = count + 1
            guess = eval(input('Nope, has to be between 1 and 100. Try again: '))
            withinRange = True if (guess <= 100 and guess >= 1) else False
        rng = 'low' if guess < magicNumber else 'high'

    print('\nYou entered the right number!')    

    print('Number:',magicNumber)
    print('range of last guess was too',rng)
    print('Number of guesses:',count + 1)
```

Last time, I was told that I didn't provide enough information about my program. And I hope I didn't over do it with the comments. This is my goal/question/inquiry/objective: I want to add some line of code into the program to have it terminate after 7 tries.

What the program does now is accept guesses over and over until the right one is reached. But I want to add some code that kills it after the 'count' variable reaches 6. The count variable goes up each time a guess is entered. Regardless of whether it is correct or not.

Any suggestion would be awesomely appreciated, Thanks in advance wizards!

Comment: have you never heard of `break`?

Comment: don't repeat yourself, you have the same code before the loop and in the loop. use `while True:`.

Comment: I have, but I can't really think of how to add it in there. I guess I could do like, `if count > 6: break`. But where would I put that though, as the first line? Assuming thats what I would need right

Comment: @Horvath Thanks I didn't think of that. It would shorten the code a few lines. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with the code.

Please don't use `eval()` to convert a string to an integer. `int()` does this without the security risks of `eval`.

In your while loop you compare `var1` and `var2` with `var`. What is `var`? You didn't define it anywhere. I guess you meant `magicNumber`. Then in the loop you set `var2` and `var3`. Why `var3`. You don't use it. And least, the best way to get the two numbers for the addition would be to get one number with the maximum of `magicNumber` and just calculate the second number.

`True if (guess <= 100 and guess >= 1) else False` could be written as

```
True if 1 <= guess <= 100 else False
```

Get rid of the duplicate code in the loop and outside of the loop. You might want to add other functions e.g. a function just for getting the input from the user and to do some basic checks.

Comment: ... and `True if 1 <= guess <= 100 else False` could, in turn, be written as `1 <= guess <= 100`.

Comment: It could - and should!

Comment: @Matthias I very much appreciate the suggestions/corrections. For a noob who's code is going to be very terrible in the beginning, it's hard to get any actual help from the more experienced programmers. Thanks again, and I will definitely implement your advice when re-writing the code.